# Print e-mail conversation in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

Does anybody know how (if possible) to print a whole conversation thread in Mail.app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this, at the moment. I've looked through the whole web.

Comment: The whole, really? :-)

Comment: Ahahah, nearly. ;)

Comment: How about saving each mail to PDF and then combine (drag & drop) them into one PDF and print?

Answer (score 5):

I have a work around for you that works and is a bit quicker than copying to pages.

What you do is:
1. Highlight the emails that you want to print. Either the whole thread or selecting particular emails by holding the apple key and selecting the mails.

1. Click the 'forward' button. This compiles all the emails into on big email
2. Print! and you are done.

Comment: It doesn't compile them into one big e-mail. :(

Answer (score 2):

In Mail.app on OS X 10.9, Mavericks, this is default behavior when only the conversation is selected in the inbox.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to select your thread and use the 'Save As…' feature. This will generate a RTF file with all thread messages concatenated. The RTF is then easy to convert to print or convert to PDF. I've tested this with OS X 10.11.1.

Comment: This has probably been introduced recently. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this.

Right Click on the Conversation in the Inbox Preview,
Select "Forward As Attachment" this  will separate each message,
Send to yourself, and you will be able to open each message and print or save.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible (`Version 10.3 (3273)`). Go to your email thread and `cmd + click` on every email in the thread that you want to save to `.pdf`. After that `File -> Export as PDF...`.